# How to mix a VB program with a C++ Program

Tags: c++, vb.net, vba, user-interface

I have a C++ program that I wrote, and I would like to give it a user interface. Is there any way I can run a C++ program and put the information from the program onto the UI of a VB Application?

Comment: When you say VB, do you mean VB.Net or VB6 - or even VBA (since you have tagged the question VBA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

Use

- COM
- COM Interop
- P/Invoke (a.k.a. `Declare` in VB)
- Oh, I forgot: C++/CLR if you intend to use Windows only

I suggest you write the whole application in a managed language (e.g. VB.Net) and only invoke C++ library functions for the performance critical work (or for legacy code that you already have, of course).

Comment: What about a plain-jane C interface and `Declare` on the VB side?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution would be to put your C++ code into a DLL, and call your code from VB. Have a look at this article for more information...

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/DLL/XDllPt1.aspx

Comment: The concepts are broadly the same but the details are different. For example a VB6 `Integer` is a .Net `Short`.

Answer (score 1):

you can mix C++ and .NET

easiest is if you target your C++ code to the CLR,  but you can also mix .NET and native code.

either way you basically make your C++ program a library your VB code can use.